# How Often Does Total 'Data Received' Reset in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

How often does "Data Received" and "Data Sent" reset in the activity monitor pane shown below:

[image]

Nothing I can think of (daily, since last restart, all time, etc.) seems correct given the numbers I'm getting, so I'm baffled as to what it could actually be.

I know that I've downloaded more than 24 GB since I've owned the computer, but less than 24GB today.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine a whole lot quicker if the total is in KB than GB

Empirically, every time I DL another 0.01 GB once my download figure is showing in GB - that's roughly every 10s, at 10MB/s on a 150Mb line.

Edit - changed my mind, sorry - it's looking like every 4s.
I was looking at the wrong info, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my main question is how often that number resets.  I know that I've downloaded more than 24GB since I've owned the computer, but definitely less than 24GB today

Comment: ahh, sorry - misunderstood. It resets at reboot - see my answer on http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215959/in-activity-monitor-what-time-frame-is-the-data-sent-received-data-from/215964#215964

Comment: Actually - it ***may*** reset at relog, but I pretty much never relog without reboot

Comment: That makes sense.  I was thrown off because it didn't reset after the computer went to sleep for being out of power.

Comment: Cool. I'm going to flag this as a duplicate of the other - which in no way reflects on the question's 'quality' it just gives twice as many people chance to Google it in future.