# Resetting Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, network, activity-monitor

I read [In activity monitor what time frame is the data sent / received data from?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215959/in-activity-monitor-what-time-frame-is-the-data-sent-received-data-from) and understand that Activity Monitor data received/sent is from system boot.

Is there a terminal command or other method to reset it, without the full reboot? (I am running Yosemite on a 2010 MacPro FWIW)

Comment: I could see such a tool or process  breaking code if this value is expected to increase monotonically. What’s the issue with doing math to subtract from a fixed point or just reboot when it’s important to clear the pipeline of analytic data?

Comment: The writing it down is what I’ve done. Preferable to a reboot. It seems to me there are those here with far more technical skill than me, and a good chance I’d see an answer ‘here’s a terminal command to do that’. Not critical, but it would have been nice to know if it were possible.